# How to see python symbolic names of objects on cursor hover of menu items in Blender 2.8

Tags: python, interface

in Blender 2.79 one could hover over a UI element and see the symbolic python name of said element. How would one accomplish the same with Blender >= 2.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Python Tooltips* needs to be enabled in *Edit > Preferences > Interface*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You simply go to Edit/Preferences.../Interface and tap the Developer Extras checkmark.